# NVL between subqueries in HIVEQL and Talend

Tags: hive, hiveql, talend, nvl

Is it possible to call nvl when there are subqueries between them? Code is below.

```
     NVL(
            (
            SELECT
            MIN(DATE_TIME)AS EFFECTIVE_DATE
            FROM TEMP.DM_ZEXPIDA_FICANT Z
            WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(CURR_HC,'([^;]+)',0)  = TEMP.AB_FICANT.CURR_CODE
            AND Z.DATE_TIME                            > TEMP.AB_FICANT.DATE_TIME
            ),
            (
            SELECT
            MIN(DATE_TIME)AS EFFECTIVE_DATE
            FROM TEMP.DM_ZEXPIDB_FICANT Z
            WHERE CURR_CODE = TEMP.AB_FICANT.CURR_CODE
            AND Z.DATE_TIME > TEMP.AB_FICANT.DATE_TIME
            ) 
    )AS EXPI_DATE,
```

As we know that the system restrict us for make select inside select:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Subqueries+in+SELECT#space-menu-link-content

Also, we can only use CASE WHEN when the form is like this :

```
CASE WHEN rr IS NULL THEN kk
ELSE rr 
END AS EXPI_DATE
```

What kind of form I have to try to succeed this?

Comment: This kind of SQL (SELECT inside SELECT) may not work in hive. Please convert them to left joined sub queries. And then use them in NVL() or IFNULL(). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: how to left-join in this case?

Comment: Pls refer to answer below

Answer (score -1):

Assuming TEMP.AB_FICANT.KEY_COL as KEY in the driving table i created below SQL. Both subqueries are converted to left join. Now, if you do not have a key column, you can join on some column which is unique in AB_FICANT.

```
SELECT NVL( A.EFFECTIVE_DATE, B.EFFECTIVE_DATE) AS EXPI_DATE
    FROM TEMP.AB_FICANT DRIV
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
            MIN(DATE_TIME)AS EFFECTIVE_DATE, INNER_DRIV.KEY_COL
            FROM TEMP.DM_ZEXPIDA_FICANT Z, TEMP.AB_FICANT INNER_DRIV
            WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(Z.CURR_HC,'([^;]+)',0)  = INNER_DRIV.CURR_CODE
            AND Z.DATE_TIME                            > INNER_DRIV.DATE_TIME
            GROUP BY INNER_DRIV.KEY_COL
            ) A ON A.KEY_COL=DRIV.KEY_COL
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
            MIN(DATE_TIME)AS EFFECTIVE_DATE, INNER_DRIV.KEY_COL
            FROM TEMP.DM_ZEXPIDB_FICANT Z, TEMP.AB_FICANT INNER_DRIV
            WHERE CURR_CODE = INNER_DRIV.CURR_CODE
            AND Z.DATE_TIME > INNER_DRIV.DATE_TIME
            GROUP BY INNER_DRIV.KEY_COL
            ) B ON  B.KEY_COL=DRIV.KEY_COL
```

Comment: so you mean i have to found the key_kol?

Comment: i modified the sql a bit but i dont think that will fix this error. Do you think you have all tables in temp schema? Can you pls check if both inner SQLs are working. I can join after 2/3hrs( at office now).

Comment: Hey @thecardcaptor, is the issue resolved?